# CXF REST service is returning more than 1 http code

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, cxf, jax-rs

When I run my service, which is just a simple POST, I'm getting an HTTP 100 followed by a 200.
Is there any way to get it to just return an HTTP 200?

```
curl -D- -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @input.json http://myserver/contxt/services/rest/service/notify
```

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Thu, 17 Jul 2014 14:20:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status code 100 is not the response to the whole request. The server is telling that he has received the headers and the client should proceed sending the request body. Sending the entity with e.g. a Content-Type the server won't accept anyway would be just a waste of bandwidth.

The server should only send the status 100 if he has received the header `Expect: 100-continue`. cURL [is sending](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_20_0) this header "for POSTs with unknown sizes". This may be the case for big files.

You can try to explicitly overwrite this header:

```
curl -H "Expect:" ...
```